# Running devenv.com displays a popup dialog and hangs TeamCity build

Tags: teamcity, visual-studio-2008-sp1, devenv, teamcity-9.0

My end goal is to run a devenv.com command from a TeamCity build configuration but it's currently hanging when it reaches the deploy stage. If I run the same command from the command line on the build agent server I get a popup at the point when it reaches the deploy stage.

Should state that the solution is a mixture of VSeWSS and WSPBuilder projects for creating .wsp solution files for WSS 3.0.

The command is

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "C:\b\work\807e2e3b4b06ef27\mySolution.sln" /deploy Release /package

The dialog that gets displayed is:

[image: Source Control - Unable to Access Database]

If I hit OK in this dialog, I then get this one:

[image: Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read]

I assume it's hanging in the TeamCity build because the dialog is stopping the process. I was under the impression though that running "devenv.com" would prevent any UI elements from being shown.

Comment: Why are you running that command manually? You can achieve the same using an MSBuild / Visual Studio runner and pass through additional parameters such as targets and configuration - Then you are automating msbuild or csc. Is this a "Command Runner Build Step" that you've added? Can you share a screen shot?

Comment: If I pass the Deploy target using the Visual Studio runner I get the following error: C:\b\work\807e2e3b4b06ef27\mySolution.sln error MSB4057: The target "Deploy" does not exist in the project.

Should have stated the the solution is a mixture of VSeWSS and WSPBuilder projects for WSS 3.0.

Comment: Try passing the path to the project into the runner rather than the solution.  Also, when deploying click once applications, we normally have to target "Publish" in MSBuild rather than "Deploy". Not knowing WSS I don't know if that would help much, but might be worth a try.

Comment: Looked good for a second but then realised the build log contained the following line: [_DeploymentUnpublishable] Skipping unpublishable project. Get the same message when passing the project path.